# Add a class to a form input

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having a problem with adding a class to a form input (I'm trying to make a form validator that the border would turn red if it was empty) I can add the error class in several types of tags except the input, why does this happen? (I used class because I plan to put more forms and I was stuck right at the beginning of development)

**CSS**

```
button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 100px 0px;
}

.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
} 

.form-control {
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="digitar" id="digitar" class='form-control'><br>
            <button id='myBtn'>Clique aqui!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault()
    element.classList.add("error");
})
```

Comment: "document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')" that gives you a node list of all the inputs with that class, and in your case you need just the first so it should be `let element = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0]`, or you can use the `.querySelector()` example `let element = document.querySelector(".form-control")`, note that `.querySelector()` select elements by css selectors and in css a class name starts with `.`

Comment: but I was planning to add more entries! and the queryselector doesn't work for more inputs, right?

Comment: if you want to use it, there is `.querySelectorAll()` and that gives you a node list so for the first element example `let element = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control')[0]`

Comment: the queryselector works on only one element, is there any way to add the class at once to all forms that I plan to add?

Comment: use querySelectorAll and loop thru them. for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) const el = elements[i] // use el to add

Comment: With jquery: $('.form-control').addClass('error'). If you want to use vanilla JS you will have to loop through all elements, as getElementsByClassName gives you all the elements in the DOM with the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` return array element need change to

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0];
```

```js
let element = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0];

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault()
    element.classList.add("error");
})
```

```css
button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin: 100px 0px;
}

.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
} 

.form-control {
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="digitar" id="digitar" class='form-control'><br>
            <button id='myBtn'>Clique aqui!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get elements by document.getElementsByClassName('form-control') then you will get array of elements when there are multiple inputs with same class.

As you asked to apply validation class, there must be some specific conditions/rules will be there to apply validation by your business logic. So I suggest you to apply class based on name/id attribute

```
document.querySelector('[name="digitar"]').classList.add('error')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use css to make it.

First add the atribute `required` in your input tag.

```
<input type="text" name="digitar" id="digitar" class='form-control' required>
```

Then in your css.

```
.form-control:focus:invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

It will focus the forms that are invalid (empty).